# Width of column in table

Tags: tables

How can I set width of column in this case?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, boldline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
\caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs - přirozené pozadí}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{V{4}m{4.8cm}|m{3cm}|m{3.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1cm}V{4}}       
    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    \multicolumn{1}{V{4}cV{2.5}}{Pozorovaný objekt}  & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}cV{2.5}}{\centering Určená hodnota $E$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}cV{2.5}}{Tabelovaná hodnota energie $E$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}m{1.2cm}V{2.5}}{\centering $\mathit{FWHM}$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}m{1.2cm}V{4}}{$\mathit{NET}$}\\

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    &&&&\\[-10pt]

Energie $\gamma $-záření (FEP)& $661,68 \pm 0,02$&  661,66& 1,5&    70096\\
\hline 
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Poloha comptonovy hrany&    $478 \pm 4$&    477,34 (shoduje se s teoretickou)&  &   \\
\hline 
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Hraniční energie dvojného comptonova rozptylu&  $565 \pm 12$&   554,58& &   \\
\hline 
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Poloha píků zpětného rozptylu&  $182 \pm 4$&    184,32& &   \\

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

    \end{tabular}
\label{Cs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to horizontlly center the text in the first row of the column while at the same time allowing linebreaks if the text is too long, you could define a new column type `C` as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, boldline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
\caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs - přirozené pozadí}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{V{4}m{4.8cm}|m{3cm}|m{3.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1cm}V{4}}       
    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    \multicolumn{1}{V{4}C{4.8cm}V{2.5}}{Pozorovaný objekt}  & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{3cm}V{2.5}}{\centering Určená hodnota $E$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{3.5cm}V{2.5}}{Tabelovaná hodnota energie $E$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1.5cm}V{2.5}}{\centering $\mathit{FWHM}$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1cm}V{4}}{$\mathit{NET}$}\\

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    &&&&\\[-10pt]

Energie $\gamma $-záření (FEP)& $661,68 \pm 0,02$&  661,66& 1,5&    70096\\
\hline 
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Poloha comptonovy hrany&    $478 \pm 4$&    477,34 (shoduje se s teoretickou)&  &   \\
\hline 
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Hraniční energie dvojného comptonova rozptylu&  $565 \pm 12$&   554,58& &   \\
\hline 
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Poloha píků zpětného rozptylu&  $182 \pm 4$&    184,32& &   \\

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

    \end{tabular}
\label{Cs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As requested in the comments, I have right aligned the first column and added a bold line between the first and second column:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, boldline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
\caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs - přirozené pozadí}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{V{4}R{4.8cm}V{2.5}C{3cm}|C{3.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1cm}V{4}}       
    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    \multicolumn{1}{V{4}C{4.8cm}V{2.5}}{Pozorovaný objekt}  & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{3cm}V{2.5}}{\centering Určená hodnota $E$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{3.5cm}V{2.5}}{Tabelovaná hodnota energie $E$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1.5cm}V{2.5}}{\centering $\mathit{FWHM}$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}C{1cm}V{4}}{$\mathit{NET}$}\\

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    &&&&\\[-10pt]

Energie $\gamma $-záření (FEP)& $661,68 \pm 0,02$&  661,66& 1,5&    70096\\
\hline 
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Poloha comptonovy hrany&    $478 \pm 4$&    477,34 (shoduje se s teoretickou)&  &   \\
\hline 
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Hraniční energie dvojného comptonova rozptylu&  $565 \pm 12$&   554,58& &   \\
\hline 
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Poloha píků zpětného rozptylu&  $182 \pm 4$&    184,32& &   \\

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

    \end{tabular}
\label{Cs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. And please, how to align white cells of left columb to right and other white cells to center? Is it possible to set vertical line between first and second colomb bold and rows and other vertical lines in white part thin? Thank you

Comment: @Elisabeth: I have edited my answer to include an updated version of the code that incorporates your requests. I hope that suits your needs.